# In Brownie, Do you need always need .address to use a contract as an contract address variable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, python, brownie

new to Brownie as I have been using mostly tutorials. I am trying to use a contract address as a variable to deploy another one, and want to know does adding the ".address"  e.g : ContractXY.address is necessary ?

Does it make any difference in terms of gas optimization or any other parameters?? I did a print, and it showed the same result in terms of value.

`ContractXY = _FirstContract.deploy()`

`XY_var = _SecondContract.deploy(ContractXY.address)`

vs

`XY_var = _SecondContract.deploy(ContractXY)`

Thank you for the help, and glad to be a part of this community.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it both ways and no, I don't think the ".address" part is a necessity and as far as deployment, I don't think there will be any difference in the usage of gas

```
>>> contract2 = deployContract.deploy(contract1,{"from":account})
Transaction sent: 0xeef5213bf540967ffb2dbbf398dab5187424033d7fcd811d8438dc49e334dfac
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
  deployContract.constructor confirmed   Block: 2   Gas used: 205549 (1.71%)
  deployContract deployed at: 0x602C71e4DAC47a042Ee7f46E0aee17F94A3bA0B6

>>> contract3 = deployContract.deploy(contract1.address,{"from":account})
Transaction sent: 0x0f15e77b7556c82418e45d7afe7029a535955abbd1c46b35bfd047b9efb67846
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 2
  deployContract.constructor confirmed   Block: 3   Gas used: 205549 (1.71%)
  deployContract deployed at: 0xE7eD6747FaC5360f88a2EFC03E00d25789F69291
```

but i belive the ".address" part is a better convention (makes the code more readable)